# Launch/Execute a file using lua?

Tags: lua

I am creating a lua script that makes creating scripts for a game easier, I would like to, after creating the desired file.lua, for windows to execute and open that file.

Is it possible?

Ok, what i need is to os.execute() a lua file and open it in windows using the default .lua reader.

Comment: I don't want to turn into an executable, i just want to open a file in windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.execute('filename.lua')` should open the file in the default application registered for .lua extension. The first value returned will be `true` if successful. It will keep the console window open though; if you want to avoid it, use something like this instead:

```
os.execute('start "" filename.lua')
```